# Using lex and yacc

Tags: linux, yacc, lex

Where do i download lex and yacc for linux?

And how do i intall them?

Comment: `apt-get install flex bison` , or whichever package manager your linux distro uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `lex` and `yacc` should be part of one of your development toolchains.

How to get them depends entirely on your distro.

For example, in Ubuntu, you would kick up Synaptic and search for, hmmm, let me think, ..., yes, that's it, "lex" or "yacc" - I knew it would come to me :-)

---

Sorry, got a little carried away there. Actually, you're more likely to have luck looking for `flex` and `bison`. The `bison` program is the GNU version which is upward compatible with `yacc`, and `flex`, while not GNU, is still free (both speech-free and beer-free).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much recent experience with Linux but back when I was doing some compiler development on Irix we used Flex and Bison.  Those are, as far as I remember, more modern versions of Lex and Yacc, and may be easier to find for  your distro.